# Can't pass a variable by reference

Tags: php, oop, reference, pass-by-reference

I am really confused with this one. Here's my code

```
class inner
{
    var $val = 0;   
}

class outer
{
    var $obj=null;

    function outer()
    {
        $this->obj = new inner;
    } 

    function get_obj()
    {
        return $this->obj;
    }
}


$app = new outer;

$obj = &$app->get_obj(); //get object by reference (& is not necessary in PHP5)
$obj->val = 1; //change something
echo $app->obj->val; //check whether it affected the original object source
//here it should display 1
```

When I am testing this on my local server, which is PHP 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4, everything works fine and it displays 1. When I am testing this on my customer's PHP Version 5.2.9 server, it displays 0. Is there some known PHP bug or may be some php.ini setting that could affect this behavior?

Comment: [Works in 5.2.5](http://codepad.org/F8tWL5TH), at least, so it wasn't "new" behaviour in 5.2.10. I suspect you have a bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If not works**, try replace this

```
function get_obj()
```

By this

```
function &get_obj()
```

Usefull links:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Thanks, that works! However it doesn't solve the original problem I am having with one product but I guess now I'll need to come up with a different test.php to narrow down the issue

Comment: Returning by reference makes no difference given his code, since he never assigns to `$obj` after he gets it, and he never assigns to the `obj` inside the class after creation

Comment: He assigns to `$obj->val`, and it seems like in `PHP 5.2.9` objects not pass by reference by default. What about assignment he assign to `$obj` inside the class after creation in constructor - `outer::outer()` - (treated as constructor in PHP version before 5.3.3). More info at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @azat: "objects" are not values in PHP 5. They cannot be "passed". `$obj` is an *object reference*, which is passed or assigned the same as any other thing. It is returned by value, since he is not returning by reference correctly. But that is irrelevant. As I said in my comment, he never assigns to the `obj` inside the class after creation.

Comment: @newacct, he did this inside the class, in constructor `outer::outer()` : `$this->obj = new inner;`, this is old form of constructor. And what another part of comment it is not correct. Read this first http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php : "objects are passed by references by default"

Comment: @azat: Read it again: "often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true." Also, constructor = creation of the object. Is that now what I said?

Comment: @newacct, sorry, now I understand. And what about `he never assigns to the obj inside the class after creation`? He did this, do you agree?

Comment: @azat: what I am trying to say is, inside the class `outer`, `$this->obj` is only assigned to in the constructor (`outer::outer()`), i.e. when the `outer` object is created, in `$app = new outer;`. By returning by reference, `$obj = &$app->get_obj();`, it makes `$obj` be tied to `$app->obj`, i.e. assignment to one would have the same effect as assigning to the other. However, after the return by reference line, nothing in the code assigns to either one. So the returning by reference makes no difference. It makes no difference if he does `$obj = $app->get_obj();` instead.

Comment: @newacct, it seems like he just confused PHP5 with PHP4.

Answer (score 2):

PHP5 and above will pass all objects as a reference. Everything else gets passed by value.

But this may not be the case if a certain directive is enabled. Check if [zend.ze1_compatibility_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.ze1-compatibility-mode) in your php.ini is active. Taken from the PHP docs:

> [...] It affects the cloning, casting (objects with no properties cast to FALSE or 0), and comparing of objects. In this mode, objects are passed by value instead of reference by default.

Hope this solves the problem...

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be this directive. Thanks!

Comment: Objects are not values and cannot be passed. Object references are values (object reference is what you get when you do `new SomeClass`), and can be passed by value (if no `&`) or by reference (with `&`), just like everything else.

Answer (score -1):

Check the client's php.ini file, there's gotta be something fishy. I'm searching on google, I can't find any bugs that people have had with call by reference on 5.2.9.

And, try azat's suggestion.

Comment: this is not call by reference. this is returning by reference